# Excel formula to check/match data between two sheet in different orientation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to check this source data (*Source Sheet*) with data in *output sheet*. I tried using two logic using IFS, but the second logic gets bypassed

Source Sheet

[image]

Output Sheet

[image]

```
=IFS(Ouput!B2=INDEX('Source'!$D$5:$D$685,MATCH(Output!B2,'Source'!$D$5:$D$685,0)),"OK",C2=INDEX('Source'!$E$5:$Y$685,MATCH(Output!B2,'Source'!$D$5:$D$685,0),MATCH(Output!A2,'Source'!$E$4:$Y$4,0)),"FINE")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to getting the formula you require but not quite there.

Provided `Output!B2` is a valid company in the `Source` sheet, then the first condition of your `IFS`

`Output!B2=INDEX(Source!$D$5:$D$685,MATCH(Output!B2,Source!$D$5:$D$685,0))`

will always be `TRUE`.

As a consequence of this, your formula will always return `OK` and the second condition of your `IFS` will never be tested.

(An `IFS` function contains a series of condition/value pairs which are considered in order. The function stops when it encounters a condition that is `TRUE` and delivers the corresponding value as its result. Subsequent condition/value pairs are, in effect, ignored.)

If you remove the first condition/value pair from your formula and change the `IFS` to an `IF` then you will be testing whether the value in `Output!C2` matches that shown in `Source` for the column with year given by `Output!A2` and row with company given by `Output!B2`.

For example:

`=IF(Output!C2=INDEX(Source!$E$5:$Y$685,MATCH(Output!B2,Source!$D$5:$D$685,0),MATCH(Output!A2,Source!$E$4:$Y$4,0)),"FINE","MISMATCH")`

There are 3 possible results for this formula

- `FINE` - Values in `Output!A2`, `Output!B2` and `Output!C2` are consistent with the `Source` sheet
- `MISMATCH` - The value `Output!C2` is inconsistent with that in the `Source` sheet for the value in the column with year given by `Output!A2` and row with company given by `Output!B2`
- `#N/A` - Either `Output!A2` is not a valid year in the `Source` sheet OR `Output!B2` is not a valid company in the `Source` sheet (OR possibly both).

The formula simply takes the second condition from your original formula and uses this as the condition part of an `IF` function. `IFS` returns `#N/A` if none of its conditions are `TRUE` so, in this case `IF` is preferable to `IFS` because it allows an error caused by an invalid year or company (in `Output!A2` or `Output!B2`) to be distinguished from an inconsistent value in `Output!C2`.